# Annoying MySQL Error

Tags: mysql, wordpress

This is the output I'm getting from the $wpdb->show_errors from Wordpress, and the output of the Query.

WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1]

1

```
INSERT INTO wp_posts (
to_ping, post_author, pinged, comment_count, post_password, post_excerpt, 
post_status, comment_status, ping_status, post_parent, menu_order, 
post_content_filtered, post_type, post_mime_type, post_name, post_title, 
post_content, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_modified, post_modified_gmt, guid) 
VALUES (
'', '', '', '0', '', '', 'draft', 'open', 'open', '0', '0', '', 'page', '', 
'test-page', 'This is a test!', 'This is where content goes...', 
'2010-12-08 07:38:05', '2010-12-08 07:38:05', '2010-12-08 07:38:05', 
'2010-12-08 07:38:05', 'http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=')
```

Comment: Looks to me like the query got either instantiated with, or was set earlier, with a 1 and a couple carriage returns. (unless the `1` above the `INSERT INTO` has no relation to the query that was passed.

Comment: Yeah I just found that out. It was another function I called before it, that was throwing the error. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is literally a "1" on the first line. Remove it. "1" alone is not valid MySQL syntax..

Comment: Yeah, I think I screwed up something. I deleted all the contents of the quotation marks and it worked without an error. I need to add each one of them one by one to see what I did. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

remove 1 at the first line

query is perfect